# What are the basic things to be tested when testing private clouds

Tags: manual-testing

Can anyone advise what types of testing needs to be done for private clouds.
the private cloud is basically used for data storage were the admin has control over the private cloud. User are granted permission by the admin.Used for small business, collages, students. It more of a personal cloud.

Answer (score 1):

Some of Major areas covered are

- Network latency, Response time
- (Load & Performance) Scale out on demand
- Security Testing
- CDN aspects if available

Answer (score 0):

- Functional testing for admin user which he controls private cloud.
- Security testing for admin.
- Functional testing for user which permission provided by admin.
- Load testing for data store.
- Security testing for normal user.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on the cloud. The testing you are asking about is testing on a deployed cloud, I assume you don't have a test cloud to verify things before you upgrade.

Either way, you will want to have a set of scripts that can validate the basic functionality of the cloud from a non-privileged user/tenant of your cloud and from an admin perspective, these can be as simple as checking connectivity between VMs, making sure resources can be created/deleted and connected to each other. These scripts should be non-destructive and clever enough to clean after themselves when they finish. They should be run regularly, but specially before and after upgrades.

Another useful test for the cloud is image verification. Making sure imported images are functional and ready to use (discard/remove otherwise).